# How can I recover SPL tokens from an account that is nested inside another ATA account?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, wallet, spl-associated-token-account

We have a Kin account that is nested under a USDC account.  We have 2 USDC accounts, and the Kin is nested under a USDC account [1] that wasn’t created by the Associated Token Account program [2], therefore we can’t use the RecoverNested instruction (introduced in Solana PR [3]) for that reason.

It's validation checks fail as it expects the Kin to be nested under the other USDC account [2].

relevant links:

- [1] first USDC account: https://explorer.solana.com/address/8ux94QJAtjYwckTecmkT9V5yqNTkRr8CFmWuCogKqShb/tokens?cluster=mainnet&display=detail
- [2] ATA program USDC account: https://explorer.solana.com/address/5trjVzHL7uQnmwzBreE83i2rnCYMjqijU1MAVbM2JPuZ/tokens?cluster=mainnet&display=detail
- [3] Solana recovery program PR: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/2889

Answer (score 2):

Since your first USDC account is *not* an associated token account, it means that there is a private key associated with it, just like a wallet.  Like any wallet, it can own other token accounts.

You'll need to recover the private key for the USDC account to reach the nested funds, otherwise the account is bricked, unfortunately.

It would be open up a big attack surface to allow for owners of owners of valid non-associated token accounts to move funds, so that change will not be considered.  You can ask the token issuer to freeze the nested account and reissue the tokens into a new account.

Answer (score 0):

Can't recall if this works on nested accounts, but it might be worth a look:

`spl-token gc --del_associated_accounts`

More info in the [pull request](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/2554)