# Multiple ATAs for the same mint

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, python, spl-associated-token-account

I've created a Python script that creates a wallet and monitors all SPL transactions of this wallet.

Using an example to illustrate the problem:

The generated public key belongs to account A with owner "System Program" (1111...).

SPL tokens sent to account A ended up in account B. Account B has owner "Account A". Actually not a problem, because funds are shown in account A.

This went on for a while, until suddenly SPL tokens did not end up in account B, but in account C. Account C has owner "Account B".

```
Account A (Owner: System Program)   <-- generated with Python script
|
|- Account B (Owner: Account A)     <-- SPL tokens sent to account A (or B) end up here
|
|-- Account C (Owner: Account B)    <-- ?
```

I've several questions now:

1. Why did this happen?
2. How can I access the funds that are now in account C?
3. Is there a way to prevent this from happening (i.e. creation of account C)?

Comment: You say "spl tokens": Are the tokens in B and C of the same token mint?

Comment: Also suggest reading through this, will answer 1. and likely 2. and 3. of your question too: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-an-associated-token-account

Comment: @GuiomarRaissa, yes, they are the same token mint/SPL token.

Comment: Could it be that an SPL token sent to account A ends up in account B (ATA of account A), but if someone would send it to account B, it would end up in account C (ATA of account B), and this would go on, i.e. SPL token sent to account C would end up in account D (ATA of account C), SPL token sent to account D...?

Comment: Yes, this is what happened. I've added it as an answer.

Comment: @GuiomarRaissa, thanks for your help and all the information, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned it's the same mint for both ATAs, you're dealing with a nested ATA. [This question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3776/how-can-i-recover-spl-tokens-from-an-account-that-is-nested-inside-another-ata-a) gives some more info on these and how to recover funds from them. To avoid this happening in the future, make sure that the account you're sending to is not already a token account itself. More info on how to perform this check [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/check-if-an-account-is-a-token-account).