# Please I mistakenly copied my Associated Token Address and sent USDT SPL to it instead of the normal USDT SPL address worth$9.4 Please help

Tags: associated-token-account, send-transaction

Good morning, please I mistakenly copied my Associated Token Address and sent USDT SPL to it instead of the normal USDT SPL address worth$9.4

Please what can i do to recover it. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover SPL tokens from an account that is nested inside another ATA account?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3776/how-can-i-recover-spl-tokens-from-an-account-that-is-nested-inside-another-ata-a)